# How to display a colored emoji

Tags: swift, xcode, unicode, emoji

My code:

```
let myemoji = "\u{2049}"
let another = "\u{2757}"
```

Playground result:

[image]

The Unicode U+2049 does not produce a red colored emoji like this ⁉️.
Is there anything specific to be added for this color?

Comment: Please provide your code, so that it will be easy for everyone to help :-)

Comment: @AustinMichael, thanks I added the image of my code

Comment: @MansiShah Don't post code as images, just give the text. Also why would would [U+2049](https://codepoints.net/U+2049?lang=en) be a red emoji?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek as per this link http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f468_200d_1f373 it should be red color

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I used image so that I can show the playground output as well :)

Comment: @MansiShah: Posting the code as text and the result as image is appropriate in your case. I have taken the liberty to do that for you :)

Comment: @MartinR thank you, you are not one of those angry devs in this community, inspite of being a top 0.01%. seriously much appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some characters can be displayed "as text" or "as emoji", and a
"Unicode VARIATION SELECTOR" can be used to control the presentation.
Example:

```
print("text presentation:  \u{2049}  \u{25B6}")
print("emoji presentation: \u{2049}\u{FE0F} \u{25B6}\u{FE0F}")
```

Result:

[image]

For more information, see [1.4.3 Emoji and Text Presentation Sequences](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Variation_Sequences):

> ED-8. text presentation selector — The character U+FE0E VARIATION SELECTOR-15, used to request a text presentation for an emoji character. (Also known as text variation selector in prior versions of this specification.)
>
> ED-9. emoji presentation selector — The character U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16, used to request an emoji presentation for an emoji character. (Also known as emoji variation selector in prior versions of this specification.)

or [Variation Selector-16](https://emojipedia.org/variation-selector-16/):

> An invisible codepoint which specifies that the preceding character should be displayed with emoji presentation. Only required if the preceding character defaults to text presentation.

Comment: Thanks soo much Martin!