# Unicode arrows are different for Text

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, swiftui

I'd like to display the left and right arrows

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - DisplayView

struct SpecialItemView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    // MARK: - Initializer

    @inlinable init(
        viewModel: ViewModel
    ) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    // MARK: - Computed Variables

    var body: some View {
        return Text("⬅︎ ➡︎⇐⇒")
    }
}
```

In the XCode they are displayed correctly:

[image]

But on the device they are rendered like this:

[image]

Is it possible to fix such behavior?

**EDIT**

monospaced font yields this:
code:

```
return Text("⬅︎➡︎ ⇐⇒⬆︎⬇︎⬅︎➡︎").font(.system(.title, design: .monospaced))
```

[image]

Comment: Upon trying other similar arrow symbols, it looks like those work and the specific ones you have are different sizes  Definitely strange

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534667/how-to-display-a-colored-emoji.

Comment: @MartinR Doesn't look like that helps when I try it, just makes the opposite arrow bigger no matter what placement of `\u{FE0F}` I tried.

Comment: @MartinR emoji representation of arrow is really ugly for my case

Answer (score 1):

I think it is something with Font (say combining glyphs or something)... say using

```
return Text("⬅︎ ➡︎ ⇐⇒").font(.system(.title, design: .monospaced))
```

I'm getting WYSWYG everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, but it works partially: only for the second pair